# jQuery breaking my wordpress site

Tags: jquery

I am including jQuery in my `header.php` file like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

But when doing this, it breaks my home page slider, it breaks my google maps ultimate plugins and some other things. When I exclude it, no custom jQuery runs on my page...only the slider works which must be using jQuery...

So if jQuery is already running on my site (since I have jQuery easing in the theme etc..), why is custom jQuery code I add to my files in  tags not working? However, when I include jQuery like I said above, my custom code runs, but it breaks other plugins...

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *should not* include jQuery manually. jQuery is included in WordPress by default, but isn't loaded on every page unless a plugin or theme requests it. This can be done using:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_scripts');
function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Here is function reference for [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) (the function) and [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) (the action hook).

In addition to that, WordPress is using jQuery in [no-conflict mode](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries). This means you cannot use the normal `$()` function, but have to use `jQuery()` instead. For example, instead of this:

```
$('selector').doSomething();
```

Use this:

```
jQuery('selector').doSomething();
```

Comment: While it is undoubtedly worth mentioning noConflict mode: [closures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472528/javascript-jquery-closure-function-syntax) with `$` as an argument are the way to go. IMHO, that is.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery is included in WordPress by default. There is no need to add it to a theme's header file manually.

If, when omitting manual addition, your script(s) are not working as expected, you probably include them too early, i.e. before [`wp_head()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) has run.

Also, it suggests you are not including them as you should, since then things would take care of themselves. Take a look at the [`wp_register_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) functions.

Comment: Or there is a jQuery version conflict that is causing fatal errors. +1 though.

Comment: Fair. Enuff. :)